# How can I publish a message to all Javascript subscribers for a channel using CometD?

Tags: java, javascript, cometd, ajax-polling, bayeux

Given a Java web application using CometD, how can I publish a message to all of a channel's subscribers each time a message is processed by bayeux?

For testing, I used `serverSession.deliver(serverSession, "/test-channel", map, null);`.

The result is that my Javascript client will subscribe successfully, but only receive messages 1 out of 10 tries.  So, 90% of the time, no messages are ever received by the browser, yet the Bayeux logging (level 3) shows that they are being sent to the correct channel every time.

Should I be using some form of a client session? The CometD documentation appears to be a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `localSession` seems to be the answer. I implemented this to fix:

```
ClientSessionChannel channel = localSession.getChannel(getClientChannel());
channel.publish(map);
```

The clients are now receiving all messages.

Comment: Have you tried for example publishing a message to a channel from a java client and you had expected the message to arrive to all subscribers (even the javascript/dojo ones?)If so could you, please provide the complete code of the java publishing client? I have this use case and I don't know what is wrong because the javascript client doesn't receive the message. Thanks

Comment: I was referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658643/publish-messages-using-cometd-java-client-that-can-be-consumed-by-javascript-subs